# data from nsmutable array are not visible in all methods

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsmutablearray

i know that this is basic objective C question but I have serious problems. I am having an NSMutable array which I fill with values in my connectionDidFinishLoading. i can see in NSLog that values are being assigned correctly. But when i am trying to fetch these values in DidSelectRow (as I am using a table view I get a BAD_ACESS error)

Here is my code:

```
@implementation MainMap
{

    NSMutableArray *condition ;
}
..
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
...
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
condition= [NSMutableArray array];
..adding objects..
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    //app crashes in here
NSLog(@"Condition of pressed item is %@",[condition objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);
}
```

If I place the     `condition= [NSMutableArray array];` inside ViewDidLoad I get a `SIGBART`.

Moreover I tried to place the declarations in .h file and have it as property and then synthesize it in .m but still nothing. Maybe I am missing something, so can you fix it?

Comment: Do you use ARC in this project?

Comment: Then NSAutoreleasePool has destroyed your data. I see that you already got good answer. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try `[NSMutableArray new]` instead `[NSMutableArray array]`. Then you should release `condition` in your `dealloc`-method.

Otherwise you can enable ARC (http://longweekendmobile.com/2011/09/07/objc-automatic-reference-counting-in-xcode-explained/). With ARC you must not handle reference counting by yourself.